# C# MVC - UnitTest - If PartialView file exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I need to verify, in **unit tests** (using NUnit), if a PartialView file exists in directory.

Someone knows how can I verify this?

I tried these ways:

```
var result = ViewEngines.Engines[0].FindPartialView(context, name, false);

var result = ViewEngines.Engines[0].FindView(context, name, null, false);
```

But none of them was run properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look on [FluentMVCTesting](https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.FluentMVCTesting)

Test would look like this:

```
using MyApp.Controllers;
using NUnit.Framework;
using TestStack.FluentMVCTesting;

[TestFixture]
class HomeControllerShould
{
    [Test]
    public void Render_default_view_for_get_to_index()
    {
        var controller = new HomeController();
        controller.WithCallTo(c => c.Index()).ShouldRenderDefaultView();
    }
}
```

More examples on their page.

Comment: It doesn't verify if the PartialView file exists in directory. :(

Comment: that's a shame. I did not use it for partials, but it helped me some time ago with controller tests, until I gave up on that.

Comment: BTW, the FluentMVCTesting is very useful! Thank you.